# What is most efficient way to monitor an EditText line for user input?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have an EditText set up for user input.  As soon as the user types any character I want that to trigger a floating label to rise above the EditText line.  What is best method to see when user has typed in the first character on the EditText line?  TextWatcher?  Others?

partial Activity file:

```
...
private ListenerEditText cListenerEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);

    cListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);
    cTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.ToDo_text_input_layout);

    cListenerEditText.requestFocus();
    cListenerEditText.setHint("To Do");
```

partial layout xml file:

```
...
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/ToDo_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

<com.example.jdw.fourthscreen.ListenerEditText
    android:id="@+id/CEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHighlight="#30D5C8"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="51"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/DEditText" >

</com.example.jdw.fourthscreen.ListenerEditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: you can add textchange listner to edittext

Comment: Ok, great I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To monitor and/or control text input, we usually use `TextWatcher` or `InputFilter`.

For your case, I believe `TextWatcher` is the right way to do.

Comment: Ok, do I only need to use onTextChanged method?

Comment: Yes, or afterTextChanged, either one.

Comment: What is difference then between onTextChanged and afterTextChanged?

Comment: You should not change the text in onTextChanged, while you can change the text in afterTextChanged. And the parameter received is different. For your case, it should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor user typing event in `EditText` you can use `TextWatcher`.

You can use `afterTextChanged()` method to check every typed character.

Below is code for adding `TextWatcher` to `EditText`.

```
cListenerEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "afterTextChanged:\t" +s.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I use Android Studio and I see that onTextChanged and beforeTextChanged method stubs are auto-generated.  Can I safely remove those to keep codes lines to a minimum?  Or do they need to stay with afterTextChanged method?

Comment: TextWatcher is  interface. you must have to implement those methods whether you used them or not